# SELinux Preventing Apache Start

Tags: selinux

When running in strict mode, SELinux would not let me start HTTPD since my mod_jk.so module was copied from an external server.

I copied mod_jk.so externally since I couldn't find the package to install it.

But, now, in order to run HTTPD, I need to put SELinux in Permissive mode.

I read on the [wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) that I could add a custom policy to allow this mod_jk.so to be used.

Is this the recommended way so that I can use my external mod_jk.so file?

Comment: What was the denial logged in `audit.log`?

Answer (score 2):

List the current security context of the file:

```
# ls -lrtZ /full/path/to/mod_jk.so
```

Compare the output with the expected context for that path:

```
# matchpathcon /full/path/to/mod_jk.so
```

Restore the expected security context of the file:

```
# restorecon -v /full/path/to/mod_jk.so
```

Restart the web server and check for new AVC denials:

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts recent
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this same issue on a Centos 7 machine with HTTPD 2.4. Took me a while, but dug up an old redhat bug report from 2007 (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=225452) which solved it.

The solution (in my case):

Modify your jk.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ to write the Shm Files to /var/run/mod_jk instead of /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
e.g.

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
JkShmFile     /var/run/mod_jk
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

No need to set SELinux to permissive

Answer (score 1):

By this command i am able to run `mod_jk` in `httpd`:

```
# grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```